# Firebase Web Auth Error: The email id is already in use by another account

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an web app using firestore and i'm also using the firebase authentication but for some days i'm facing an unique problem.

Whenenver i'm trying to register with any email or password, the same error is thrown "**The email id is already in use by another account**". I dont know what's happening.

The code is shown below

```
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn',true);
          window.location = '#!/dashboard';
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    });
    }).catch(function(error) {        
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        alert(errorMessage);
    });
```

Everytime i'm using different email id for registering but still shows the same error. I've seen the firebase console, there also no user is added.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.